# Add namespace to a specific node of XML using XSLT in six field

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

You can help me please, I need an XSLT to add the namespaces to the tags.
The namespaces to add is **xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common"** in six fields.

Current XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:consultarDeudaResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/schema/GenericService/Deuda/Consultar/Resp-v2014.12">
   <ns1:Identificador1>864821006</ns1:Identificador1>
   <ns1:IdTransaccion>567657</ns1:IdTransaccion>
   <ns1:Canal>014</ns1:Canal>
   <ns1:Sucursal>1</ns1:Sucursal>
   <ns1:Biller>67</ns1:Biller>
   <ns1:CodigoServicio>50469</ns1:CodigoServicio>
   <ns1:CodigoError>0</ns1:CodigoError>
   <ns1:GlosaError>Transacción OK</ns1:GlosaError>
   <ns1:Documentos>
      <ns1:Documento>
         <ns1:Identificador>00112399</ns1:Identificador>
         <ns1:Monto>226578</ns1:Monto>
         <ns1:Fecha>2022-05-17</ns1:Fecha>
         <ns1:Dato1>64821006</ns1:Dato1>
         <ns1:Dato2>0000014716</ns1:Dato2>
         <ns1:Dato3>0</ns1:Dato3>
         <ns1:Dato4>0</ns1:Dato4>
         <ns1:Dato5>0</ns1:Dato5>
      </ns1:Documento>
   </ns1:Documentos>
</ns1:consultarDeudaResponse>
```

The expected output should be:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:consultarDeudaResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/schema/GenericService/Deuda/Consultar/Resp-v2014.12">
   <ns1:Identificador1>864821006</ns1:Identificador1>
   <ns1:IdTransaccion>567657</ns1:IdTransaccion>
   <ns1:Canal>014</ns1:Canal>
   <ns1:Sucursal>1</ns1:Sucursal>
   <ns1:Biller>67</ns1:Biller>
   <ns1:CodigoServicio>50469</ns1:CodigoServicio>
   <ns1:CodigoError>0</ns1:CodigoError>
   <ns1:GlosaError>Transacción OK</ns1:GlosaError>
   <ns1:Documentos>
      <ns1:Documento>
         <ns1:Identificador xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">00112399</ns1:Identificador>
         <ns1:Monto xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">226578</ns1:Monto>
         <ns1:Fecha xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">2022-05-17</ns1:Fecha>
         <ns1:Dato1 xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">64821006</ns1:Dato1>
         <ns1:Dato2 xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">0000014716</ns1:Dato2>
         <ns1:Dato3 xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">0</ns1:Dato3>
         <ns1:Dato4 xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">0</ns1:Dato4>
         <ns1:Dato5 xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/GenericService/Common">0</ns1:Dato5>
      </ns1:Documento>
   </ns1:Documentos>
</ns1:consultarDeudaResponse>
```

Comment: This second definition is redundant.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. The problem is that you can not have one namespace with two different definitions of it, because you define the ns1 at the start of the xml.

What i do here is i replace the namespace of your element with the ns2 and create a new element with the new name and the namespace you want including as attribute.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ersion="3.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/schema/GenericService/Deuda/Consultar/Resp-v2014.12">
    
      <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
      <xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"></xsl:output>
    
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:template>
      
      <xsl:template match="//ns1:Documento/*">
        
        <xsl:variable name="ElementName">
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(name(.), 'ns1', 'ns2')"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:element name="{$ElementName}" namespace="http://www.servipag.cl/ESB/schema/GenericService/Deuda/Consultar/Resp-v2014.12">
            <xsl:value-of select='.'></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:element>
        
      </xsl:template>
      
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are very much mistaken: the expected output CAN be produced exactly as shown (and with much less effort than your code exerts).